# How to limit a extjs grid to only show 100 rows and offer all rows as download?

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, store

I have a store that can contain thousands of records. Instead of using the paging functionality of the **extjs** grid I want to limit the grid to only show the `100` first store records and offer a link or button that allows the user to download the complete store data as tab delimited text file.

Is there a way to transform the data of an `grid` store into an tab delimited text file and offer it to download in `extjs/javascript`?

Here is the code for the store I am using:

```
var resultStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'Result',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '../asso_find.pl',
        reader: {
            root: 'data',
            totalProperty: 'totalCount'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: what proxy are you using for data loading?

Comment: Just a thought: why not limit it on the server side? :)

Comment: @Molecule: I am using an ajax proxy. I added the code of my store in my question!

Comment: @Lionel Chan: If I limit it already on the sever side there is no possibility to download the complete result set anymore.

Comment: alex, extjs store is sending `limit` param when it loads data. You can change your server script considering `limit` param.

Comment: @Molecule: Thanks a lot for your reply!!! But how do I get all the rows when I let my sever limit the result set? I would like to avoid to load the store again in order to get all rows.

Comment: You can send server [extra param](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax-cfg-extraParams). F.i. you can add to your proxy config line `extraParams: {isShouldBeLimited: true},`. Server depending on isShouldBeLimited param will limit or not.

Comment: @Molecule: But in order to get the complete result I have to set isShouldBeLimited to false. And that would still load thousands of rows into my grid right?

Comment: @alex I see, I think I know your problem, it's sort of like your data can only be generated once and you will only need to present the first 100 records, and download the whole dataset if requested?

Comment: @Lionel Chan: Exactly! The generation of my data takes some time and I don't want let the user wait again before he can download the complete data set.

Answer (score 1):

Can you add a load listener to the store and then only load the first 100 records using that. For example:

```
listeners: {
  load : function (store, records, success, operation, options) {
    store.loadData(records.slice(0, 100))
  } 
}
```

I've tested this on a combo box store and it seems to work. It might be a good start to your solution as it means that all records are on the client side but only 100 are in the grid.

Comment: Hi Eoin! I tested your code and it works! That definitly brings me closer to a solution of my problem! The only thing missing now is a possibility to offer the complete data set of my store as download in a tab dilimited format.

Comment: What he did is load up the first 100 records from the returned records. You may want to just store the records in another variable and use it for data generation later.

Comment: @Lionel is correct. If you want to use the entire resultset you will need to store it in a variable for later use. However, I'm not sure how you can generate a downloadable tab delimited text file in javascript. Have you tried this extension? http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?32400-GridPanel-directly-to-Excel.